# the contradiction between whereis python and python --version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In one Python environment, I type `whereis python`, and get the following information

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2.6-config
/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6
/usr/X11R6/bin/python2.6 /usr/X11R6/bin/python2.6-config
/usr/X11R6/bin/python /usr/bin/X11/python2.6
/usr/bin/X11/python2.6-config /usr/bin/X11/python
/usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

But when I type `python --version`, it returns `Python 3.4.5`

Are there any contradiction between `whereis python` and `python --version`. It confuses me is because the result of `whereis python` includes several folder names including `python2.6`.

Besides the above information, I also tried `which` and `alias python`

```
bash-4.1$ which python
/devl/tf_0.12/bin/python

bash-4.1$ alias python
bash: alias: python: not found
```

Comment: Some sort of link or alias exists that points `python` to `python3` Try typing `whereis python3`

Comment: Try: which python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction.  **whereis** looks through all of the paths given in your **PATH** environment variable, identifying each directory that contains an executable **python** command.

**python --version**, on the other hand, invokes the **python** indicated by the shell's disambiguation rules (for which **PATH** is only one factor), and reports the version of that executable.  Check your aliases and other environment settings for the local meaning of **python**, such as

```
alias python
```

Does that clear up the mystery?

---

**Response to question edit**

This tells us that the shell resolves the command **python** to the specific executable **/devl/tf_0.12/bin/python**.  I have no idea what is in **/devl**; this is not a standard location for any UNIX-based world with which I'm familiar.  However, if you run `/devl/tf_0.12/bin/python -- version`, you should see the same 3.4.5 that you saw before.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks for the reply. I updated the information in the original post. There are two questions, the result of which python and whereis python are very different. My understanding is that the result of which python tells us exactly the which python compilier uses. Besides, alias python does not work.

Comment: Yes, **which** tells you which of the choices gets executed.  **alias** tells you what -- if anything -- is assigned to the symbol "python", just in case some script has redefined it in the current environment.  **alias** worked just fine: it told us that there is no such redefinition.