# creating a virtual environment to support Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a python development environment supporting Python 3.4.5. Right now, I would like to create a virtual environment using vritualenv. In this virtual environment, I need to support Python 2.7 instead since some of to-be-used Python programs only work for Python 2.7. How to create this virtual environment. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use virtualenv with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Python 2.7 installed, then you can pass an argument to virtualenv to use a different Python version, like this:

```
virtualenv --python=python py27env
```

Note that is it practice that `python` points to python 2.x, whereas `python3` points to python 3.x - if your system layout is different, adjust the command appropriately.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I posted a related question in another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334455/the-contradiction-between-whereis-python-and-python-version    which includes the information of my python development environment. Based on which, it seems that I do not have python 2.7, then how should I do?