# Why does 'whereis python' give another location of python than which 'which python' when using python virtual environment?

Tags: python, bash, python-venv

I am using Python3.9 and MacOS.
I created a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv venv` command.
Inside the virtual environemt I want to check which python binary I am using.

I tried to use `which` and `whereis` bash commands and I was surprised because they give different results.

`which python` gives me the correct output: `{path_to_venv}/bin/python`.
`whereis python` gives me the system python instead: `/usr/bin/python`.

Why is it like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334455/the-contradiction-between-whereis-python-and-python-version

Comment: They are different commands. Look up the definitions of those commands in their respective man-page.

Comment: Don't use any of them, `type`, `hash` and `command` are better alternatives since this is `bash`. Try `which cd` and `whereis cd` , See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081